# How to implement choosing a solution in backtracking type problem recursively

Tags: algorithm, go, backtracking

I'm having trouble understanding how one can implement a "choice" in recursive backtracking problems.
I have the following code for finding all permutations of a given int slice:

```
func permute(nums []int) [][]int {
    res := [][]int{}
    tmp := []int{}

    var helper func( []int)
    helper = func(toChoose []int) {
        if len(toChoose) == 0{
            cp := make([]int, len(tmp))
            copy(cp, tmp)
            res = append(res, cp)
            return
        }

        for i, _ := range toChoose{ 
            tmp = append(tmp, toChoose[0])
            toChoose = toChoose[1:]
            helper(toChoose)
        }
    }

    helper(nums)
    return res
}
```

Basically as I understand, at each slot in one of the result arrays, I need to decide on choosing one of the numbers from input, example:
input: [1, 2]
for slot 0, choose either index 1 or 0
for slot 1, choose either index that remains
we get result: [1, 2], [2, 1] 
how can I implement that "decision" recursively? I think this is the key for me to fully understand backtracking and recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use next permutation algorithm. Check [this](https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm) article. This is not exactly written for Golang, but the idea is the same. Basically, given an array, next permutation performs some swap operations on the array and give you the next permutation. So, if you give them an array of `[1,2,3]`, the next permutation will be `[1,3,2]`, and then the next permutation will be `[2,1,3]`, and then `[2,3,1]` and then `[3,1,2]`, and then `[3,2,1]`. You can call next permutation over and over again to list all possible permutations.

In C++, we have this algorithm in the standard library. For Golang, I think you can check [this](https://golangbyexample.com/next-permuation-number-go/) out.

Answer (score 0):

1. How to save each element's state(it has beed used or is available), you can use like array, bit operation
2. When to quit the recursive. In your question, when all the elements in the array are been used, the recursive is over.

Here is a java example

```
/**
 * 
 * @param visited    to save using states of arr elements
 * @param arr        source array
 * @param list       the used elements in permutation
 * @param count      how many elements have beed used, when it equals arr's length, one permutation is over
 */
public void dfs(boolean[] visited, int[] arr, LinkedList<Integer> list, int count)
{

    //the end of the permutation
    if (count == arr.length)
    {
        System.out.println(list.toString());
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if (visited[i])
        {
            continue;
        }

        //to mark arr[i] has been used, you can't use it before set visited[i] to false
        visited[i] = true;

        //add arr[i] to permutation list
        list.add(arr[i]);

        //now the num of used arr elements is count+1
        dfs(visited, arr, list, count + 1);

        //remove arr[i] from permutation list
        list.removeLast();

        //now arr[i] is available
        visited[i] = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to approach permutations recursively. One method of recursion that's often applied with lists is to take one member of the list and to recurse on the rest of the list.

Then the question for you would be: given that we have all the permutations for the list without this element, what action should we perform on them with the element to achieve the permutations that include the element?

In pseudocode:

```golang
permute(nums) {
  // One base case: if nums has one element,
  // what do we return?

  var x = nums[0]
  var rest = permute(nums[1:])

  // How to apply x to each permutation
  // of the rest of the list?
  //
  // For example:
  // input [1, 2, 3]
  // rest = [[2, 3], [3, 2]]
  // What do we do with 1 and each of those
  // permutations to build permutations of
  // length 3?
}
```